# Problem with *ngFor after changes in HTML file

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-template, angular8

I have problem with *ngFor in Angular 8.

When I start Angular app (ng serve) *ngFor works great but when I change the HTML file where I use this loop (even if I add one space in other line) I have error:

```
ERROR Error: Template error: Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'li'. 
    at createUnknownPropertyError (core.js:15118)
    at elementPropertyInternal (core.js:14984)
    at Module.ɵɵproperty (core.js:16569)
    at CarListComponent_Template (car-list.component.html:5)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:14533)
    at checkView (core.js:15957)
    at componentRefresh (core.js:15715)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:14214)
    at refreshDescendantViews (core.js:14120)
    at checkView (core.js:15958)
ERROR Error: Template error: Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.
(...)
```

and when I restart app works again until change in HTML file...

Is it possible for me to change HTML files and see the changes without restarting the application.

What I tried to do:

```
F12 > disable cache
in app.module.ts import CommonModule 
in app.module.ts import BrowserModule
```

car.component.html

```html
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let car of cars">id: {{car.id}}, name: {{ car.name }}</li>
</ul>
 
<div *ngFor="let car of cars">
    id: {{car.id}}, name: {{ car.name }}
</div>
```

app.component.html

```html
<app-car-list></app-car-list>
```

app.module.ts

```js
// import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CarListComponent } from './shared/car-list/car-list.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CarListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    // CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is due to a Bug for Ivy Engine for Angular 8, check the [link](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32217) for more information.

Either Disable the Ivy Engine in **tsconfig.app.json** or update your modules to Angular 9 release candidates.

set `enableIvy` to `false` for disabling Ivy in **tsconfig.app.json**

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears because you didn't add `CommonModule` & `BrowserModule` in your module.ts file. The `CommonModule` will exports all the basic Angular directives and pipes, such as NgIf, NgForOf, DecimalPipe, and so on. Re-exported by `BrowserModule`, which is included automatically in the root AppModule when you create a new app with the CLI new command.

```
import { NgModule } from  '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from  '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I tried: CommonModule & BrowserModule, olny BrowserModule, and only with CommonModule... result was the same :(

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `?` in the for loop. That's all that's required.

```
*ngFor="let coin of btc?.data"
```

Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OptW5UXTz6U