# Angular exception - Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'li'

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 10.1.3, for reference.

All I'm trying to do is use a simple `*ngFor` loop to duplicate multiple buttons dynamically, like so:

`<li *ngFor="let prov of allProvs" class="nav-item" style="margin-right: 10px;">`

This is a really weird issue I'm having. Whenever I start the project for the first time using `ng serve` everything works fine. When there's a change made, I get this exception and it doesn't work until I use `ng serve` again:

> Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'li'.

This happens with pretty much any other tag I try to use, not just lists. I've seen another user with this issue here and he said something about disabling Ivy. Firstly, I'm not too familiar with Ivy - I tried searching for 'ivy' in my project angular.json file as that user mentioned to disable Ivy and nothing came up. Secondly, I have a feeling this isn't even the issue.

Any fix for this?

Comment: Didn't help. Everything posted there is 4 years old, too.

Comment: You should import `commonmodule` to use ngFor

Comment: May be this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57124624/angular-problem-with-ngfor-after-changes-in-html-file

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti That's exactly what someone else said (who just happened to delete his comment) and it isn't working.

Comment: @OnurBaştürk Doesn't work either. I don't even have the option to disable Ivy.

Comment: I mean try the other answer at the link. Import the commonModule and browserModule

Comment: You should not disable Ivy - it is the new rendering engine of Angular, and this problem indicates that there is something else wrong with your code.

Can your provice a working stackblitz example of your project? Or can you try and update to the latest angular version and create a new project on your pc and copy the code to see if the problem still exists?

Comment: @DareRelaqz can you post the module code where you declared your component contains above html code, I mean li code

Comment: @ForestG I'm not sure how to upload the whole thing to stackblitz but updating to the latest version did seem to fix things for me, at least for the time being.